# using pandas dataframe transpose headers into a single column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe for which i need to convert the headers related to date into a column.
[image: df]

I tried to use

```
df.set_index('id')
df.unstack()
```

but i don't get to the desired output.

[image: output]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_index` doesn't operate in place by default. You need to either assign the output or chain your operations.

```
df.set_index('id').stack().reset_index(name='value')
```

Comment: `df.set_index('id').unstack().reset_index(name='value')` seems to give what i need

Answer (score 0):

also this answer (meanwhile deleted by the author) seems to work:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='id', var_name='date')
```